How to control the placement of the bibliography of pandoc
I use pandoc to convert some org-mode files with bibliography to HTML. And I need to place the bibliography at a specific location instead of the very end of the HTML.
The placement of the bibliography can be done in Markdown files. But I cannot figure out how to do the same for org files. More specifically, for a Markdown file mybib.md:
---
bibliography: 'mybib.bib'
nocite: '@*'
...

Bibliography
============

::: {#refs}
:::

# Appendix

Something here.

The following command generates the correct HTML:
pandoc  --citeproc --bibliography=mybib.bib  mybib.md -o mybib0.html

, where mybib.bib is:
% Encoding: UTF-8
@www{extreme_programming,
    author = {Don Wells},
    title = {Extreme Programming},
    date = {1999},
    url = {http://www.extremeprogramming.org/when.html},
}

The HTML output is roughly:

Bibliography
1 D. Wells, “Extreme programming,” 1999.
http://www.extremeprogramming.org/when.html
Appendix
Something here.

But when I do this with a similar org-mode file:
#+NOCITE: @*
* Bibliography

# \printbibliography
<<refs>>

* Appendix

Something here.

using the command pandoc  --citeproc --bibliography=mybib.bib  mybib.org -o mybib.html, the HTML output has the bibliography at the end of the page.

Bibliography
Appendix
Something here.
1 D. Wells, “Extreme programming,” 1999.
http://www.extremeprogramming.org/when.html

I am not sure what makes the org-mode route different.
How can I control the placement of bibliography in org-mode files in above?

Surely that's a question for pandoc, not for Org mode (or Emacs).

Exporting org to markdown preserves the placement?

Could you try placing the line
`#+print_bibliography:`

where you want the bibliography to be printed? (This would be the standard Org syntax for specifying the location.)

@Simka Thanks. I tried that just now with the pandoc command, it still places the bibliography at the end.

@Simka is right, this syntax is recognized by pandoc, too. If it doesn't work, then raise a bug for pandoc.
